# auto fit for column with grid images

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

Please help me. I have 2 problems.

1. I need to create a gid follow the bellow image. Now I can use GridLayout to build it. But with GridLayout I can't set auto fit for column.

2. And I can't set layout_rowSpan & layout_columnSpan in java code. I tried this code but it's not work

```
convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams(
                    GridLayout.spec(4), GridLayout.spec(2)));
```

[image: grid images]